# Access React state of function enclosed inside useRef doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I'm trying to access React state inside a function enclosed inside of `useRef`. However, even with a helper function bound to `App` to access the state, the state never updates inside of the `useRef` function.

```
getCount outside 0
// after clicking, getCount inside is still 0, even though count now equals 1
getCount outside 1
getCount inside 0
```

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const App = function () {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const getCount = function () {
    return count
  }.bind(App)

  console.log('getCount outside', getCount())

  const onClick = useRef(() => {
    console.log('getCount inside', getCount())
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        increment count
      </div>
      <div onClick={onClick.current}> 
        {count}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

const wrapper = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, wrapper)
```

Comment: change `setCount(count + 1)` to `setCount((count) => count + 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument passed to `useRef` is only considered when the component mounts. Only at that time is the value assigned to the ref; it won't update when the component re-renders.

When the component mounts, the `count` variable that the ref's function closes over is the initial state value, which is 0. No matter how many times the component re-renders, the ref's function, if not reassigned, will still close over that original state value.

If you want the ref's function to result in an up-to-date value, assign it anew each time there's a re-render.

```
// assign nothing notable on mount, just create a ref
const onClickRef = useRef();
// on mount and on re-render, assign a function
// with an up-to-date reference to the state variable
onClickRef.current = () => {
  console.log(count);
};
```

Though, in React, usually it'd be better to pass the state itself down and use it, rather than a ref - refs are generally for things that you can't accomplish using the more functional tools provided by React.

Comment: Great, thanks for this answer. I realised I can just update state inside of my ref function, and then respond to this state update as an effect outside of the ref.

For anyone curious as to the use case, I'm getting `Invariant Violation: Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported` when passing a regular function to `onViewableItemsChanged` for `ScrollView` inside of React Native.

Answer (score 1):

**Using callback with previousValue in setter solves this problem:**

```
const onClick = useRef(() => {
  console.log(count); <----- always 0 (initial state)
  
  setCount((previousValue)=> {
    console.log(previousValue); <---- correct current value each time
    return previousValue+1;
  }
})
```

**Source:** idea was from @bogdanoff's first comment from the question. Upvoted.